# In-App-Purchase Receipt verification Sample not working

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I'd like to know that why the sample can not be referenced in my project. However, the sample is for Windows Phone 8 Technology(it's mentioned clear) still I'm facing the problem to referenced the project. I'm working on a project where I've to verify the receipt of the purchased product. I'm including the sample in my project and then tried to reference it. It shows me the following error on referencing.

Error: `Unable to add the specified project reference. The reference must be a Windows Phone project that targets the current or earlier version of the Windows Phone OS.`

You can find the sample [here on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/In-app-purchase-receipt-c3e0bce4)

What wrong I'm doing? I've tried the sample only on `VS 2012 for Windows Phone` project not on `VS 2010`. if the sample runs only on `VS2010` then how could I verify the receipt on `VS 2012`.

Please suggest your valuable answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this sample in Windows Phone8 project (assuming it is your intent), because receipt verification is external process to your phone application typically it can be on your server where receipt validation should be done (if needed).

see IAP purchase and verification diagram at below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206949(v=vs.105).aspx