# How to get In App Purchase receipt in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, in-app-purchase, windows-phone, receipt

I have included in app purchase in my app and I have used this method GetProductReceiptAsync and I have also tried the following:

```
  string xReceipt= await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(PRODUCTID, true);
```

I want to get receipt in xml format.how to do it?
I have tried this link:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/In-app-purchase-receipt-c3e0bce4
But this link shows how to do receipt verification and I want to get receipt.

as mentioned in this link: [In-App-Purchase Receipt verification Sample not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961433/in-app-purchase-receipt-verification-sample-not-working)
I am also not able to add references,i am using VS express 2012 and creating app in WP8.

Answer (score 0):

In your line of code variable *xReceipt* contains the receipt which is in xml format. You can throw a messagebox alert for this variable on your debug build.