# Verify Signature after in app purchase

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I want to verify the digital signature for in app purchase. I don't know how do I accomplish this. I got so many sample and links but they are not working.
Here is the [Receipt verification sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/In-app-purchase-receipt-c3e0bce4) and [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/windows/apps/jj649137.aspx) to verify purchase using receipt.

Problem is, the link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=246509&cid=xxxxxxxxxxxxx returns Page not found exception and SignedXml,X509Certificate2 is not not present in windows phone 8.

Also the sample is for Windows phone 8 but when i add the sample project in my project i got error in referencing. I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961433/in-app-purchase-receipt-verification-sample-not-working) before.

So plz guide me how can I verify the purchase using this digital signature?

Comment: Are you able to run the sample? It sounds as though you're trying to use this in code that doesn't specifically target 8.0. Is this correct? IAP can only be used in WP7.1 projects via reflection.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, i can view the files of the sample but not able to run the sample. however its written on the sample page that it is for windows phone 8. Tell me how can i run the sample and test the IAP